# Getting the optional value inside an array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Given an optional array of type Book, declared in a table view controller class:

```
var books: [Book]?
```

Later in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)

    let book = books?[indexPath.row]

     cell.textLabel?.text = book?.title

    return cell
}
```

Now, so far I have only seen this books array optional unwrapped using if let statement in order to loop through the array.
But why in cellForRow here do we not unwrap books and unwrap book instead of adding another ? after it, as in `books?[indexPath.row]` and `cell.textLabel?.text = book?.title`

Comment: Because the `text` property is optional. If it weren't optional you'd have to do  `cell.textLabel?.text = book!.title!`

Comment: The inferred code is `let book: Book? = books?[indexPath.row]`. That's why you have to unwrap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to unwrap `books` or `book` because the `text` property of the `UILabel` is an optional `String?`. The only time you have to unwrap optionals is if you're using the retrieved value in some context that doesn't accept an optional. But `text` does, so your example operates fine.

My problem with this syntax is that, while it's a useful shorthand, this is a bit sloppy. If there is a programming problem (for example, `books` is `nil` when this is called even though that technically shouldn't be possible), the code in the question will silently continue executing and you will be left scratching your head, wondering why the label in the cell was blank. (This is also true for patterns that suggest using `guard` statements, quietly returning the `cell` if the unwrapping failed.)

But I strongly disagree with suggestions provided elsewhere that `books` should not be an optional. If this array cannot be populated at the time the view controller is instantiated, then `books` *should* be an optional (and be `nil`) until such time that this information is retrieved.

Bottom line, there is a difference between state of "`books` has not yet been set" and "`books` was populated, but no records were returned". This is the purpose of optionals, to avoid arbitrary sentinel values like "empty array" to indicate that `books` does not have its value set. (I am sympathetic to those who object to the sloppy overuse of optionals, but this simply is not one of those cases. And I'm not buying the `Optional` performance overhead concern, either, because it is immaterial in this example and it strikes me as a perfect example of premature optimization.)

I believe, instead, that you should (a) leave `books` optional; but (b) detect if it is unexpectedly `nil` and report this as the error it is, because if `cellForRowAt` is called, it must not be `nil`.

Thus, I would suggest:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookCell", for: indexPath)

    let book = books![indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = book.title

    return cell
}
```

This accomplishes what we want, populating the label correctly, but will also immediately take the developer to the offending line of code if there was a code logic error and `books` was `nil`.

Now, many developers have a maniacal aversion to using the `!` forced unwrapping operator. Personally I think it's fine because it's a fundamental programming error if `books` was `nil` when this method was called, and the forced unwrapping operator will stop my execution at the offending line and I'll know precisely what the issue is.

But, if you really want to avoid the forced unwrapping operator, `!`, then use a `guard` statement, triggering an informative `fatalError` if `books` is `nil`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookCell", for: indexPath)

    guard let book = books?[indexPath.row] else {
        fatalError("No book found")
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = book?.title

    return cell
}
```

The key is that if a situation arose where `books` was `nil`, you want to know immediately in the development process, not left guessing what the source of the problem was.

To be clear, this forced unwrapping and/or `fatalError` pattern should *never* be used in situations where the unwrapping could ever fail for reasons outside of your control. For example, don't use these patterns when parsing responses from remote web service or processing user input. You want to gracefully handle errors that might have resulted outside of your control. But if it is a true program error for a particular scenario to take place, then forced unwrapping and/or `fatalError` approaches are advisable so logic errors are immediately apparent, rather than forcing you to hunt around looking for the source of aberrant app behavior.

Comment: I don't fully understand this: Bottom line, there is a difference between state of "books has not yet been set" and "books was populated, but no records were returned". Is this a question of optional vs. nil object/empty array?

Comment: Yes, that's my point. The purpose of optionals is "this variable has not yet been set." I strongly disagree with the assertion elsewhere that a model object like `books` must not be optional. Yes, don't use optionals where inappropriate (e.g. if every `Book` must have a title, then `title` should not optional). But, one shouldn't extrapolate from this to say that your `books` object must not be optional. I think `books` not only can be, but in many cases should be, an optional. I also disagree with the "silently return if unwrapping fails" pattern, whether with optional chaining or `guard`.

Answer (score 1):

**Never** declare a data source array of a non-optional table view or collection view as optional.

```
var books = [Book]()
```

That makes your life so much easier

```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)

   let book = books[indexPath.row]
   cell.textLabel?.text = book.title
   return cell
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but would suggest adding a reference for your strongly worded opening :)

Comment: In practice the view makes no difference between your two cases. The result is *show no items*.

Comment: @brandonscript It's just illogical to use an **optional** data source for a **non-optional** view.

Comment: @vadian I agree - but your wording implies that there is more to it than just lack of logic ;) Perhaps "You don't need to" or "you gain nothing by..."

Comment: Never say never. There are very good and valid uses for the data source array to be optional. Perhaps you are loading the data asynchronously and your data source methods need to differentiate between there being no data and the data not yet being loaded.

Comment: @rmaddy I do say never. The delegate method `numberOfRows` does not care about *maybe*. It expects a non-optional number of items. In practice an optional data source is nonsensical.

Comment: It's not cumbersome when it's useful. I might want to show a "loading" row when the data source array is nil, for example.

Comment: Yes, of course, but there are better methods to handle that than an optional data source. Even your *"loading" row* is actually non-optional from the perspective of the (table) view.

Comment: @vadian I have deleted my previous comment thinking that I misunderstood you. But I didn't. So just to recap, "never declare datasource object as optional", is something that can be absolutely the opposite of what you're saying. It is very handy to have an optional collection, because when it's nil you have 0 number of items, when e.g. your data request finishes, all you need to do is to reload tableview. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will never be called unless number of items is more than 0, thus datasource not nil. So you can safely force unwrap. It's a very handy pattern.

Comment: No, it's *never declare datasource object **of a non-optional view** as optional*. That's a significant difference. Consider that all relevant data source methods of the view expect non-optional values. I don't vote against optionals. I vote against the abuse of optionals.

Comment: Ok. `numberOfRowsInSection` returns myItems?.count ?? 0. `myItems` is an optional, but you're providing a real value as the datasource, which is 0. And `cellForRowAt` doesn't even get called if number of items is 0. So I really don't get what's your catch.

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` is called very often. Isn't `return myItems?.count ?? 0` more expensive than `return myItems.count` from the performance point of view ... ? I'm just fighting for writing the most efficient code.

Comment: Yes technically it's more expensive than just providing a value immediately, but come on, there is plenty of memory and processing power to unwrap an optional.

Answer (score 1):

An optional unwrap using `?` means that *if* the value exists, unwrap it. This is ok to do (safe to do) if you don't plan on using the potentially nil value elsewhere. In your case, you could technically do it this way (it will compile, and likely won't crash), but it's not the safest way, because now you're relying on each piece along the way to support a nil value.

That said, you don't really need to declare your array as optional. Because you're enumerating the number of rows of data anyway, the array should always exist. The variable is **the number of rows it contains**, not **whether it exists or not**. In other words: checking that the array exists *on top of checking the number of rows* is just extra work for the compiler and extra code for you to write.

You can also take advantage of `guard` too, reducing the amount of code that executes if you don't have good data:

```
// ...
guard let book = books[indexPath.row] else { return cell }
cell.textLabel?.text = book.title
return cell
```

Comment: Superb and v helpful answer as well but Vivian above hammered the point home and showed how simple it is without optionals. But thanks for your help on this. To ask a stupid question tho: by enumerate, do you mean count, or go through?